# I have some trouble with fwrite() and fread()

Tags: c++, windows, fwrite, fread

```
#define ARRAY_SIZE 10

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    // create array mas1 of ARRAY_SIZE integers and fill it with random values
    int array1[ARRAY_SIZE]{ 10, 78, 23, 81, 50, 15, 24, 26, 90, 59 };

    // write ARRAY_SIZE integers from array1[] to f1.txt
    FILE* f1;
    fopen_s(&f1, "f1.txt", "w+");
    fwrite(array1, sizeof(array1[0]), ARRAY_SIZE, f1);

    // read ARRAY_SIZE integers from f1.txt to array2[]
    fseek(f1, 0, SEEK_SET);
    int array2[ARRAY_SIZE];
    fread(array2, sizeof(array2[0]), ARRAY_SIZE, f1);

    // print array1
    cout << "array1: ";
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        cout << array1[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;

    // print array2
    cout << "array2: ";
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        cout << array2[i] << " ";
    }
}
```

output:
array1: 10 78 23 81 50 15 24 26 90 59
array2: 10 78 23 81 50 15 24 -858993460 -858993460 -858993460

Why array1 outputs normally but array2 is not?
I use Visual Studio 2019

Comment: Did you check the return values of `fwrite`, `fseek`, and `fread`?

Comment: The file is not open in binary mode.  Did you look at the file contents that you're reading?

Comment: There are many things you can do before you have to ask anyone for help. You can inspect the contents of the file and see what if anything was written there. You can use a debugger to run your program, one line at a time, inspect the values of all variables, and observe its logical execution flow. If you want to learn C++ effectively, you have to put in some effort in debugging and troubleshooting your own code, instead of asking strangers on some web site.

Comment: Not only is the file not open in binary mode, when it's not, Windows treats any byte with a value of 26 as marking the end of the file. And which element of your array is the first one that's not being read?

Comment: @OP [Use examples that demonstrate how this is done](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fread)

Comment: *Why array1 outputs normally* -- Of course it outputs normally.  You created an array, and outputting it in a `for` loop.  That has nothing to do with the erroneous file operations.

Comment: @Shawn No it doesn't. Ctrl/z as end of stream only happens when you type at the console.

Comment: @user207421: are you sure?  On WIndows (where control-Z indicates EOF), a text file containing control-Z has the EOF at a byte containing decimal 26.  The file is a text file (no `b` in the open mode).   If the file is opened in binary mode, that does not apply.

Comment: @user207421 Wanna bet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify your fwrite as

```
fwrite(array1, sizeof(int), ARRAY_SIZE, f1);
```

And fread as

```
fread(array2, sizeof(int), ARRAY_SIZE, f1);
fclose(f1)
```

Comment: Modifiy it so why?

Comment: The code using `sizeof(array1[0])` or `sizeof(array2[0])` is fine — it is equivalent to what you propose, except that if the type of the array changes from `int` to, say, `double`, the original code needs no change whereas yours does.

Comment: Also, note that you can edit an answer of yours while it is deleted and then undelete it.  That's usually better than deleting one answer and submitting a second.